# How to get data from external api?

Tags: javascript, angular, single-page-application

I'm new to Angular2. I'm going to write single page app and I need possibility to get json from my backend.

I found a lot of examples online but no one works for me... :/ I spent 2 days trying to run this and debug...

I wrote this code:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {Http, Response} from 'angular2/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

export class Comp {
    id:number;
    name:string;
    cmd:string;
    builds:[Build]
}

export class Build {
    id:number;
    name:string;
    status:string;
    component_id:number;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
      <h1>MYAPP</h1>
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="#comp of comps">
          <b>{{ comp.name }} <=> {{ comp.cmd }}</b>
          <ul>
            <li *ngFor="#build of comp.builds">
              <b>{{ build.name }} <=> {{ build.id }}</b>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  public comps;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getComps();
  }

  getComps() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:4000/components')
      .map((res:Response) => res.json())
      .subscribe(
        data => { this.comps = data},
        err => console.error(err),
        () => console.log(this.comps)
      );
  }
}
```

I want to get Comp model from web and show it using @template. I tried to debug this in Google Chrome console and this.comps variable is undefined. Application gets json from backend, but I don't know why can I use it and store in variable.
I suppose that I have a small mistake in my code, but I don't know where. :(

Can anybody help me?

Comment: What does the console say?

Comment: put a breakpoint in this lambda: `data => { this.comps = data},`  and see if it gets called.

Comment: just initialize the `comps` at the start of class before use,and have you import  `HTTP_PROVIDERS` ? than try to get console hope it helps.

Comment: breakpoint ?? which breakpoint @TamasHegedus

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

Comment: I don't have errors on the console.
While I debug I see that "this.comps" is udefined but console.log(this.comps) function prints data to output. I see my object in console but it isn't match to my Comp object.

Comment: @LukaJacobowitz: When I add code to my view to show comps I see [Object object] on the webpage.

Now I would like to convert this object to Comp class because without this ngFor doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, try to write your code here in "plnkr.co" we may run your code and make some forks that works ...

Answer (score 1):

Verify that `res.json()` in `.map((res:Response) => res.json())` contains the data that you think it does.

I suggest creating a helper method and setting a breakpoint as follows:

```
getComps() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:4000/components')
      .map(this.extractData)
      .subscribe(
        data => { this.comps = data},
        err => console.error(err),
        () => console.log(this.comps)
      );
  }

private extractData(res: Response) {
    if (res.status < 200 || res.status >= 300) {
        throw new Error('Bad response status: ' + res.status);
    }

    //set breakpoint here and value of body.
    let body = res.json();

    //some web servers package the API call return value in a .data object.
    //others do not. So, we check to check...
    if (body) {
        if (body.data) {
            return body.data;
        }
        else {
            return body;
        }
    }
    else {
        return [];
    }

}
```

I was having the same problem and it turned out that IIS Express was *not* packaging the return value in a `.data` object, and without the `if(body){...}` checking code above, the `ngFor` was choking on an empty `{}` object.

Answer (score 0):

it should work :)

```
   @Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `
  <h1>MYAPP</h1>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="#comp of comps">
      <b>{{ comp?.name }} <=> {{ comp?.cmd }}</b>
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="#build of comp.builds">
          <b>{{ build?.name }} <=> {{ build?.id }}</b>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
`
```

cheers

Comment: Not work, I've got errors on console:
angular2.dev.js:23925 EXCEPTION: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays. in [comps in AppComponent@4:12]BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:23925
angular2.dev.js:23925 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:23925
But my code gets data from api, because I see it in log. I can't bind data to my model...

Comment: Ok now it is clear when you wrote the error msg,
You have to do tell the parser how to parse your data from the 
 resources apis: (http://localhost:4000/components)..
Can your write the "json " data that you need to parse?

Comment: This is my json data: {"data":[{"name":"test","id":1,"cmd":"test cmd","builds":[{"status":"1","name":"test","id":1,"component_id":1},{"status":"1","name":"test2","id":2,"component_id":1},{"status":"1","name":"test3","id":3,"component_id":1}]},{"name":"test","id":2,"cmd":"test cmd","builds":[{"status":"1","name":"test32","id":4,"component_id":2}]}]}

Comment: please correct your data json format use this tool [link](http://zaa.ch/jsonlint/)

Comment: no it isn't , so we can not help you I tried to make you a project on plnkr to show yu how it work but you I found that your problem is that you don't know how to write a valid JSON data. I am sorry

Comment: I double checked with json lint, it is valid. I wrote ruby code to parse this json, it it valid.

Anyway, I created project in react.js and everything works fine with this json. :)

Comment: look at this tool it don't lie, it tells you that your json is not valid http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=1d8fbc03cc28fb844bf86fa631fcaf9d

Answer (score 0):

If your JSON data is an array of Comp object than you have to do these two steps:

1. `export class Comp {
   id:number;
   name:string;
   cmd:string;
   builds:Build[];//this was your first fault
   }`
2. public comps; // this should be-->   private comps:Comp[];
   you don't need it to be public but it have to be an array/list

Comment: I change my code and now I get a exception in console: EXCEPTION: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays. in [comps in AppComponent@4:12]